# According to Russell, are sense data NOT the only things immediately known, or are they not purely mental?

Tags: empiricism, bertrand-russell, idealism, berkeley

In *Russell*'s **Problems of Philosophy**, in refutal *Berkeley*'s argument for idealism -in Russel's words "whatever can be immediately known must be in a mind"- he states:

> Berkeley was right in treating the sense-data which constitute our perception of the tree as more or less subjective, in the sense that they depend upon us as much as upon the tree, and would not exist if the tree were not being perceived. But this is an entirely different point from the one by which Berkeley seeks to prove that whatever can be immediately known must be in a mind.

From this I can only conclude that either:

1. *whatever can be immediately known* includes something other than *sense-data*.
2. *sense-data* is something not purely mental.

Now if **1** is correct, then the question remains as to what is there besides *sense-data* that can be *immediately known*. (Besides "internal" things, i.e: memories, dreams, etc.. We can't take these into account since the point of idealism was to prove that even things existing "outside" are ideas).

But if **2** is correct, then what is the real meaning of *sense-data*? To explain my current conception of *sense-data*: I take the "red" *sense-data* to be the "redness" that **I see**. and if I were to **hear** "red" (as could happen to people with [Synesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia)) it would no longer be the same thing ("red"), even if it is caused by the same physical thing and there would be a one-to-one correspondence between the "red_"s that I hear and the "red"s that I see.
 Hence I take "red" to be something purely personal and mental. So if it is not purely mental (since we're supposing **2**) it must have some other meaning as **Russell** uses it. What is that meaning?

Answer (score 1):

The SEP chooses to put it like this

> > it was intended only to denote that which we are directly aware of in perception. The term's meaning was supposed to be neutral between direct and indirect realist theories of perception, so that it was not to be assumed either that sense data must by definition be mind-dependent or that they must be mind-independent

So 1 is false, but 2 is not necessarily true.  Something can be dependent in common on several things at once, and sense-data depend both on the sense and on the origin of the sensation.  There has to be some point in the process of apprehension where data enters the mind.  The 'stuff' at that point is sense-data.  It is perceived directly, but it originates partly outside the mind, or it could not be entering.

To assume entirely otherwise -- that nothing enters the mind -- puts the tree in the mind, and takes you down Berkeley's path to where there is only one mind.  If I and you both perceive the tree, and the tree is in the mind, one or both of us does not exist.

This conception is from before modern theories of probing perception suggested that perceptual information flows both ways, to meet in the middle.  The mind *makes the guess* that the red is likely, and queries the sense for validation or rebuttal.  In that case the 'red' is entirely inside the mind, but the test criteria for redness still uses facts from outside of it, and *those* become the sense-data, but not exactly in Russel's sense.

Theories that do not allow for the mind taking an active role in apprehension, by asserting assumptions about qualia, generally fail to explain why we really perceive the exact same physical data in different ways in different contexts.

Comment: The thing is, I don't see a problem with his refutal of idealism (in the sense that either there is nothing beside ideas or ideas (sense-data) are independent from "outside"). My main concern is that he also seeks to refute "whatever can be _immediately_ known must be in a mind.". Now with sense-data being the only things _immediately_ known, in order to disprove that specific statement he would need to prove that not only are sense-data _caused_ by something "outside", but they _are_ partly from "outside".

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that sense-data, at the point where they're being perceived (before that it can't be called sense-data) is in fact purely mental.

Comment: Well, things either get into the mind, or they don't.  I offered the more modern theory that they originate in the mind and are potentially destroyed by contact with the outside.  But then the *data* is still really partly from outside.  There either is a limit point, where the two meet, or there isn't.  If you reject outright dualism, there is a boundary around what is mental.  Personally (assuming you didn't read read both endings) I am of two minds psychoanalytic/Hermetic dualism and this notion of the mind probing physical reality, as captured in modern theories of perceptual construction.

Comment: @user2268997 (forgot to tag the comment above)

Comment: The probing perception theory makes a surprising amount of sense. But how is "the data really partly from outside" if "they originate in the mind and are potentially [only] destroyed by contact with the outside"?

Comment: The fact the assumptions fail and disappear is still *data*.  If the reasons why they fail is physical, there is still a transfer of information from the physical to the mental world.  The theory makes the flow of sensory information like the flow of current in electricity.  It traces the movement of where things aren't.  Sensory information does not exist, except as the removal of conflicting qualia.  When you get down to a consistent possibility, then you have an idea.  But that absence is caused by a physical test.  And you can call that 'killing off point' the locus of sense data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60608/discussion-between-jobermark-and-user2268997).